# How to make pattern by hovering with mouse

Tags: javascript, css

I have a pattern code I want to execute it by just hovering for example.

I want if the user hovered picture 1 => 2 => 3 => 6 => 9 in a row, an alert is shown in the browser and writes your pattern was true. But it is not working.

How can I change it to it show the alert when we follow this 1 then 2 then 3 then 6 then 9th photo.

```js
var code = arman1(2);

function arman1(code) {
  var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
  var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
  var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
  var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
  var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
  var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
  var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
  var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
  document.getElementById('end1').innerHTML = (code + 1);
}

function arman2() {
  var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
  var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
  var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
  var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
  var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
  var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
  var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
  var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
  document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = (1);
}

function arman3() {
  var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
  var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
  var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
  var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
  var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
  var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
  var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
  var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
  document.getElementById('end3').innerHTML = (1);
}

function arman6() {
  var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
  var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
  var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
  var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
  var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
  var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
  var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
  var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
  document.getElementById('end6').innerHTML = (1);
}

function arman9() {
  var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
  var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
  var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
  var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
  var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
  var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
  var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
  var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
  document.getElementById('end9').innerHTML = (1);
}
```

```html
</script>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p1" onMouseOver="arman1()">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p2" onMouseOver="arman2()">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p3" onMouseOver="arman3()">
<br>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p4">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p5">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p6" onMouseOver="arman6()">
<br>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p7">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p8">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.pngg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p9" onMouseOver="arman9()">
<p id="end1"></p>
<p id="end2"></p>
<p id="end3"></p>
<p id="end6"></p>
<p id="end9"></p>
```

Comment: Start by initialising `code`  correctly - you can also concatenate the code to be a string or "12369" and test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a common function `arman` and match the collected user pattern with the correct pattern already defined like the snippet below shows.

```js
var correctPattern = '12369';
var userPattern = '';

function arman(code) {
  userPattern += code;

  if (correctPattern === userPattern) {
    alert('Right Pattern :D');
  }
}
```

```html
</script>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p1" onMouseOver="arman(1)">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p2" onMouseOver="arman(2)">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p3" onMouseOver="arman(3)">
<br>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p4">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p5">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p6" onMouseOver="arman(6)">
<br>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p7">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p8">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.pngg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p9" onMouseOver="arman(9)">
<p id="end1"></p>
<p id="end2"></p>
<p id="end3"></p>
<p id="end6"></p>
<p id="end9"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

On hovering on each image push the corresponding image index to an array, and on hovering image 9 compare whether the indexes are correct. Hope this will help you.

```js
var code = arman1(2);
var patternArray = [];
function arman1(code) {
    var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
    var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
    var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
    var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
    var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
    var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
    var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
    document.getElementById('end1').innerHTML = (code + 1);
    patternArray = [1];
}

function arman2() {
    var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
    var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
    var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
    var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
    var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
    var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
    var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = (1);
    patternArray.push(2);
}

function arman3() {
    var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
    var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
    var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
    var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
    var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
    var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
    var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
    document.getElementById('end3').innerHTML = (1);
    patternArray.push(3);
}

function arman6() {
    var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
    var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
    var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
    var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
    var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
    var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
    var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
    document.getElementById('end6').innerHTML = (1);
    patternArray.push(6);
}

function arman9() {
    var picture1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var picture2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    var picture3 = document.getElementById('p3');
    var picture4 = document.getElementById('p4');
    var picture5 = document.getElementById('p5');
    var picture6 = document.getElementById('p6');
    var picture7 = document.getElementById('p7');
    var picture8 = document.getElementById('p8');
    var picture9 = document.getElementById('p9');
    document.getElementById('end9').innerHTML = (1);
    patternArray.push(9);
    checkPattern();
}

function checkPattern() {
    if(patternArray[0] == 1 && patternArray[1] == 2 && patternArray[2] == 3 && patternArray[3] == 6 && patternArray[4] == 9 && patternArray.length == 5) {
        alert("Your pattern is correct");
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p1" onMouseOver="arman1()">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p2" onMouseOver="arman2()">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p3" onMouseOver="arman3()">
<br>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p4">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p5">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p6" onMouseOver="arman6()">
<br>
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p7">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p8">
<img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8312582376/pattern.pngg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="p9" onMouseOver="arman9()">
<p id="end1"></p>
<p id="end2"></p>
<p id="end3"></p>
<p id="end6"></p>
<p id="end9"></p>
```

Comment: by this if we hover the last one it show the pattern is true

Comment: @Arman Not just on the last one. It should go in the order 1 2 3 6 9 then only it will alert.